# Can`t import pygame to VScode despite having it installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, pygame

I'm using pip 21.2.4 and python 3.9.7

I'm pretty sure I have pip installed since if I run `pip --version` in the terminal it gives me `pip 21.2.4 from C:\Users\rohaan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`

If I run `pip install pygame` in the terminal I get `Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\rohaan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (2.0.1)`

Despite the requirement being satisfied when I `import pygame` I get  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: maybe you have more then one python version installed? check the actual python version by running `python -v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you have multiple versions of python installed on your device, one has the module and the other tries to run the file, go to the control panel and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not using the python interpreter which you have installed the `pygame` package.

You can execute this code to verify which python interpreter you are using:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Then you can switch the python interpreter to which you have installed the packages or you need to activate the environment before you want to install the package in order to install the package to the right place.

[image]